# Error while counting number of occurrences of a character in a string

Tags: c++, string, data-structures

If the string s="abcac" and n=10, the substring we consider is abcacabcac, the first 10 characters of her infinite string. There are 4 occurrences of "a" in the substring.

My code is working fine for the above and some other examples but when I input the string s="a" and n = 1000000000000, I'm getting the output as 0. I can't understand why I keep getting 0;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

long repeatedString(string s, long n) 
{
    long long count = 0;

    string s1 = s;
        //adding the string upto n times
    for (long long i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        s += s1;
        if (s.size() >= n)
            break;
    }
        //looping to find number of occurances of "a"
    for (long long i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == 'a')
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    string s = "a";
    long n = 1000000000000;  //getting 0 for this input
    long p = repeatedString(s, n);
    cout << p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you get if you do `std::cout << sizeof(long);`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I got sizeof(long) = 4

Comment: `1000000000000` is too big to fit in a 4 byte integer.  switch to using `long long` and it should work

Comment: You can also do std::cout << n to see what the actual input to the function is. Likely you are passing it a negative number (integer overflow) thus i < n always terminates without entering the loop.

Comment: You are not supposed to create the very long string and count in that. You can do this by counting the occurences in the original string and applying some arithmetic.

Comment: You are constructing a string bigger than your system's memory. Look at your comment where it says "n times" and think what that would be in math class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an overflow at `long n = 1000000000000;` max of 4 byte int is `2,147,483,647`.

you are mixing types in the for loops too which will cause overflow.

You may consider checking the compiler warnings: [Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vxDFoa0QnCRTNbJU)